# How can `cat /proc/$pid/cmdline` take several seconds?

Tags: swap, ps, proc

I encountered this strange behavior yesterday on one of our servers. `ps`, `pgrep` and `htop` (on startup) were very slow. `strace ps` showed that `read('/proc/$pid/cmdline`) took several seconds on some processes. Why did this happen?

Some observations:

- The processes executable was on NFS
- The processes (about 20+) were doing `unlink` and `symlink` operations on files also on NFS, in parallel
- They're forked from the same parent process
- There're 80GB of RAM available (mostly cached), but swap (only 4GB) is in full use
- I run `while true; do cat /proc/$pid/status; sleep .1; done`, `cat` returned immediately if `State` is `S` or `R`, but took several seconds when `State` is `D`

I did some Google'ing and found some SO answers suggesting that when `State` is `D`, reading `/proc/$pid/cmdline` would stall. Is that true? And how does that work? Why was `/proc/$pid/cmdline`, which was set before the program started, affected by what it was doing after that?

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109864
- https://superuser.com/questions/250554/why-does-my-system-hang-when-i-run-ps-w-and-possibly-other-commands
- https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2014/10/27/ps/

Comment: Could you post your kernel version and the contents of `/proc/$PID/stack` of the hanging `cat` process?

Comment: I upvote for the question AND the links, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, reading /proc/$pid/cmdline for a special $pid was very slow, even when State is R. And thanks to the links above which point out it might related to NUMA, I found out it caused by numad moving processes from nodes to nodes, this is from /var/log/numad.log :

```
Thu Jul 18 20:06:41 2019: Advising pid 9565 ($name) move from nodes (0-1) to nodes (1)
Thu Jul 18 20:06:45 2019: PID 9565 moved to node(s) 1 in 3.91 seconds
Thu Jul 18 20:11:50 2019: Advising pid 9565 ($name) move from nodes (1) to nodes (1)
Thu Jul 18 20:12:00 2019: PID 9565 moved to node(s) 1 in 9.72 seconds
Thu Jul 18 20:17:05 2019: Advising pid 9565 ($name) move from nodes (1) to nodes (1)
Thu Jul 18 20:17:23 2019: PID 9565 moved to node(s) 1 in 17.85 seconds
Thu Jul 18 20:22:28 2019: Advising pid 9565 ($name) move from nodes (1) to nodes (1)
Thu Jul 18 20:22:51 2019: PID 9565 moved to node(s) 1 in 22.73 seconds
Thu Jul 18 20:27:56 2019: Advising pid 9565 ($name) move from nodes (1) to nodes (1)
Thu Jul 18 20:28:23 2019: PID 9565 moved to node(s) 1 in 26.88 seconds
Thu Jul 18 20:33:28 2019: Advising pid 9565 ($name) move from nodes (1) to nodes (1)
Thu Jul 18 20:33:44 2019: PID 9565 moved to node(s) 1 in 15.49 seconds
```

When moving processes, read cmdline is slow, because cmdline is from user space and kernel need to lock(?) the page and read.

I guess the later move from the same node1 to node1 is needed because the process 9565 was on node1, but it might use remote memory.

```
% numactl -s
policy: default
preferred node: current
physcpubind: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
cpubind: 0 1
nodebind: 0 1
membind: 0 1
```

Thanks.